# Disable record owner transfer for ONE profile for only ONE object

Tags: administration, developer, app-development

I need to disable the ability to change a record owner, but only for the Lead object, and only for one Profile. Is this possible?

Alternatively/Additionally, is there a way to remove the "change owner" button from the mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should they be able to edit the record at all? If not, you could simply remove the `edit` ability for that object for that one profile.

Otherwise, a [validation rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) should work well. You can specify the conditions you'd like:

```
anytime the Owner field changes
AND
it's the profile you're stopping
```

In actual, correct syntax

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
$Profile.Id = '' //insert profile Id here
)
```

To **avoid hard-coding the ID**, you can use a couple different options:

1. Use Profile Name instead

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
$Profile.Name = '' //insert profile name here
)
```

2. create a custom permission and give it to that profile.

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
$Permission.Prevent_Lead_Owner_Edit)
)
```

3. create custom metadata that contains the name of the profile and/or ID so you can easily change it across many different validation rules in one location.

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
$User.ProfileName = $CustomMetadata.Profile_Mapping__mdt.YourProfileName
)
```

For the [button on the mobile app](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329119&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), you should be able to remove the action from the page layout for that object if the profile has its own layout.

Comment: `$Profile.Name` should work too in lieu of `$User.ProfileId`, no? (except in a multi-language org)

Comment: Definitely, just slipped my mind. Added as well.

Comment: Thank you- good advice